# Regex ignores first "less than" character

Tags: javascript, regex

Test String:

```
From: John Smith <johnsmith@gmail.com> Date: Fri, 12 Jan 2018 13:56:47 -0500 Message-ID: <CAOiWwegyRC+FE75Ezw3AxiCbNegswuQz8eLCCO0=hFGsLA@mail.gmail.com> Subject: test email To: bobsmith@yahoo.com
```

When trying the regular expression:

```
From:.*<
```

It completely ignores the first `<` next to "johnsmith@gmail.com" and skips to the proceeding one next to `<CAOiWwegy...`

What do I need to modify in my regular expression for it to not skip the first `<`?

Comment: Regex quantifiers are *greedy* by default. Use `.*?` to make it *lazy* or even better `[^<]*` since it doesn't backtrack.

Comment: You could also try:   From:[^<]+< which sounds like what you are looking for

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to search for.

Answer (score 1):

```
.*
```

matches a lot of things, and it does so in a greedy way.

```
From:[\sA-Za-z]*
```

is probably what you're looking for.

or

```
From:[^<]*
```

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

Your pattern `From:.*<` uses `.*`. The `*` quantifier is *greedy*. What this means is that it will match any character any number of times and, so long as the pattern is satisfied, it will continue to match as many characters as possible. So in your case it will match up until the last occurrence of `<` because that's how it's designed to work.

---

### Code

Below are a couple of methods that you can use to match up to the first occurrence of `<` (after `From:`)

#### Lazy Quantifier

This method makes the quantifier `*` *lazy*. What this means is that it will match any character any number of times, **but as few as possible**. I think Microsoft's documentation on [Backtracking in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backtracking-in-regular-expressions) does a good job of explaining it:

> When a regular expression includes optional quantifiers or alternation
>   constructs, the evaluation of the input string is no longer linear. [...] Therefore, the regular expression engine tries to
>   fully match optional or alternative subexpressions. When it advances
>   to the next language element in the subexpression and the match is
>   unsuccessful, the regular expression engine can abandon a portion of
>   its successful match and return to an earlier saved state in the
>   interest of matching the regular expression as a whole with the input
>   string. This process of returning to a previous saved state to find a
>   match is known as backtracking.

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/IyaHhH/1)

```
From:.*?<
```

#### Negated Character Set

This method uses a negated character set to match any character *except* a given character (in your case `<`). This method is usually regarded as better than using a lazy quantifier because it doesn't backtrack (therefore it performs better). Comparing both of these methods (and according to regex101) the *Lazy Quantifier* method takes 23 steps to match your string whilst this method only takes 11 steps to match the same.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/IyaHhH/2)

```
From:[^<]*<
```